# Java, LibGDX, Rectangle intersection fails with negative dimensions?

Tags: java, libgdx, intersection, rectangles

I am making a unit selector for use in an RTS game, in Java with LibGDX. I have created a rectangle to check if the units hitbox collides with the hitbox of the selection, and if so the unit is added to a list of selected units.

If I drag the mouse in one direction the units are selected, in the other, (when a rectangle with negative width/height is created they are not). Do you have any suggestions for why this is.

Thanks.

Code for selector:

```
boolean selectInProg = false;
public List<Entity> createSelection(List<Entity> entities){

    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){

        if(!selectInProg){

            xDown = Gdx.input.getX();
            yDown = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY();
            selectInProg = true;

        }

        hitbox.set(xDown, yDown, Gdx.input.getX() - xDown, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) - yDown);

    }else{

        hitbox = new Rectangle();
        selectInProg = false;

    }

    List<Entity> selected = new ArrayList();

    for(Entity entity : entities){

        if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(hitbox, entity.hitbox, new Rectangle())){

            selected.add(entity);
            entity.selected = true;

        }

    }

    return selected;

}
```

[image: Arrow shows mouse movement during selection, on the left the entities are selected. On the right they are not.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from **[here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.java)** and **[here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.java)**, that is because of `Rectangle.overlaps`:

```
public boolean overlaps (Rectangle r) {
    return x < r.x + r.width && x + width > r.x && y < r.y + r.height && y + height > r.y;
}
```

This code assumes that the widths/heights of the rectangles have the same sign. So if `x` describes the left or right side of **both** rectangles, it works. The same applies to `y` of course. However, if `x` describes the right side of rectangle 1 and the left side of rectangle 2, it does **not** work.

I suggest you simply construct your Rectangle to override `overlaps`:

```
hitbox = new Rectangle(){
    public boolean overlaps (Rectangle r) {
        float left = Math.min(x, x + width);
        float right = Math.max(x, x + width);
        float top = Math.min(y, y + height);
        float bottom = Math.max(y, y + height);
        float left2 = Math.min(r.x, r.x + r.width);
        float right2 = Math.max(r.x, r.x + r.width);
        float top2 = Math.min(r.y, r.y + r.height);
        float bottom2 = Math.max(r.y, r.y + r.height);
        return left < right2 && right > left2 && top < bottom2 && bottom > top2;
    }
};
```

It is then just important to pass `hitbox` as first argument to `Intersector.intersectRectangles`, but you do that already.

Of course you can also back the above in a one-liner if you like those more:

```
hitbox = new Rectangle(){
    public boolean overlaps (Rectangle r) {
        return Math.min(x, x + width) < Math.max(r.x, r.x + r.width) && Math.max(x, x + width) > Math.min(r.x, r.x + r.width) && Math.min(y, y + height) < Math.max(r.y, r.y + r.height) && Math.max(y, y + height) > Math.min(r.y, r.y + r.height);
    }
};
```